# How to guarantee Spring bean order? PropertyPlaceHolder issue

Tags: spring, properties, initialization

I have a very simple and small service which I am using spring.
To configure the database connection I have a DataSource bean and I use a "datasource.properties" file that is loaded using .

The deal is that Spring is initializing the datasource bean before reading the properties file and this way, the datasource bean is trying use the "${datasource.driver}" driver.

How can I guarantee that the properties are loaded before initializing the datasource bean?

See a piece of code below:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:config/datasource.properties"/>
<import resource="classpath:spring/spring-*.xml"/>

<bean id="bdsDatasource"    class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"   destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass"    value="${datasource.bds.driver}" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl"        value="${datasource.bds.url}" />
    <property name="user"           value="${datasource.bds.user}" />
    <property name="password"       value="${datasource.bds.password}" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 2):

#### *if*

- `property-placeholder` is used in the same app context, and
- `<import resource="classpath:spring/spring-*.xml"/>` does not have its own `property-placeholder` that overrides the one defined before the import statement, and
- `datasource.properties` really has a `datasource.bds.driver`

#### *then*

`bdsDatasource`'s `${datasource.bds.driver}` should be resolved with no problems.

#### *In case*

there *is* another `property-placeholder` somewhere that overrides the one defined before the `import` statement, here are two things to try:

- define your `property-placeholder` *after* the import statement:

```xml
<import resource="classpath:spring/spring-*.xml"/>
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:config/datasource.properties"/>

<bean id="bdsDatasource"    class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"   destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass"    value="${datasource.bds.driver}" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl"        value="${datasource.bds.url}" />
    <property name="user"           value="${datasource.bds.user}" />
    <property name="password"       value="${datasource.bds.password}" />
</bean>
```

- add an `order` attribute to the `property-placeholder`:

```xml
<context:property-placeholder 
    location="classpath:config/datasource.properties" 
    order="0"/>
```

to potentially override the order of several `property-placeholder` beans

Comment: How do you define a prop order when the placeholder bean you want the application to use is a subclass of PlaceholderConfigurerSupport?