# How to guarante Spring PropertyPlaceHolder been loaded before specified bean been generated?

Tags: spring, properties, javabeans

I am working with Spring 3.2 and I am trying to define some beans with property place holders.

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:/config/db2.properties"/>
<bean id="testBean" class="com.mywork.func.service.TestBean">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driver}" />
    ...
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
   <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driver}" />
   ...
</bean>
```

In the db.properties, I have

```
jdbc.driver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
```

As the two beans listed in the snippet are both defined with placeholders like "${jdbc.driver}", but I got different things for the properties in beans:
for the testBean I got "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" while in dataSource I got "${jdbc.driver}".

Some testing show that the "datasource" was init before the property-placeholder been initializated property while "testBean" was init after that.

Could anyone give me some clues how to ensure the property placeholder been initialized as early to to ensure any other beans I expected to utilize the property place holders can got proper values?

There was a question almost the same as mine, but with no effective answer to it.
[How to guarantee Spring bean order? PropertyPlaceHolder issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10126847/how-to-guarantee-spring-bean-order-propertyplaceholder-issue)

Comment: Are the two beans in the same Spring config file?

Comment: Yes, the two beans and the context property-placeholder are defined in the same spring config file.